# $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}A^{m}$ exists, and denote by $B = (b_{ij})$. Then, for all $1 \leqslant i; j \leqslant n$, we have $b_{ij}\in \{0,1\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

True/False: Let $A = (a_{ij}) \in M_{n}(\mathbf{R})$ be such that $a_{ij} \geq 0$ for all $1 \leqslant i; j \leqslant n$. Assume that $\lim\limits_{m\rightarrow \infty}A^{m}$
exists, and denote it by $B = (b_{ij})$. Then, for all $1 \leqslant i; j \leqslant n$, we have $b_{ij}\in \{0,1\}$.

My Attempt: I think it is false: But How construct a counterexample
, Give some Hints.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** A very easy way to ensure that $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty}A^m$ exists is to make it so that $A^m = A$ for all $m$.

**Further Hint:**

> Look for a $2 \times 2$, non-invertible, and upper-triangular matrix $A$ satisfying $A^2 = A$.

Comment: Does the assumpion that $\lim_{m\to\infty}{A^m}$ imply that $A^m=A$?

Comment: @bb_823 The assumption that the limit exists does not imply that $A^m = A$ for any $m$. For example, consider $A = \frac 12 I$ where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Consider
\begin{gather}
D=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
Note that $D^n=D$  $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. And let
\begin{gather}
S=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
1&-1
\end{pmatrix}\\
\therefore
S^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
0.5&0.5\\
0.5&-0.5
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
Then define
$$A=S^{-1}DS$$
\begin{gather}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0.5&-0.5\\
-0.5&0.5
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
Then
\begin{align}
A^n&=S^{-1}D^nS\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}A^n&=S^{-1}(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}D^n)S\\
&=S^{-1}DS\\
&=A
\end{align}